# Convert CameraImage Stream to Bytes or File in flutter?

Tags: google-mlkit

I am trying to use google ml kit to process an image so i extract the left eye open probability,
but it requires the input image to be either a file,bytes or file path, see below

```
final inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(file);

final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(filePath);
```

it requires one of those above, i am trying to use a Camera image stream to achieve this,

```
 _cameraService.cameraController.startImageStream((image) async {
// i am trying to convert the image received here to be converted into either a File, Bytes, File path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `CameraImage` to a `InputImage` with the following function. But be aware: This code only works for the `bgra8888` format which is single plane. `yuv420` would be multi-plane and you would have to adjust the method where it requires `Plane` data. I have tested this with Flutter 3.7.7 on an iPhone 12 / iOS 16.1 simulator. I have set `imageFormatGroup` of `CameraController` to `ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888`. This code also assumes that the rotation of the image is zero degrees.

```dart
InputImage _convertCameraImageToInputImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
    InputImageFormat? inputImageFormat;
    switch (cameraImage.format.group) {
      /*case ImageFormatGroup.yuv420:
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          inputImageFormat = InputImageFormat.yuv_420_888;
        }
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          inputImageFormat = InputImageFormat.yuv420;
        }
        break;*/
      case ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888:
        inputImageFormat = InputImageFormat.bgra8888;
        break;
    }

    if (inputImageFormat == null) {
      throw Exception("InputImageFormat is null");
    }

    InputImagePlaneMetadata inputImagePlaneMetadata = InputImagePlaneMetadata(
        bytesPerRow: cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow,
        height: cameraImage.planes[0].height,
        width: cameraImage.planes[0].width);
    InputImageData inputImageData = InputImageData(
        size: Size(cameraImage.width.toDouble(), cameraImage.height.toDouble()),
        imageRotation: InputImageRotation.rotation0deg,
        inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
        planeData: [inputImagePlaneMetadata]);
    return InputImage.fromBytes(
        bytes: cameraImage.planes[0].bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);
  }
```

Resources:

- [CameraImage class](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraImage-class.html)
- [InputImage class](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_mlkit_commons/latest/google_mlkit_commons/InputImage-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

ML Kit team doesn't own the flutter_mlkit repo, so please file issue at https://github.com/azihsoyn/flutter_mlkit/issues

Answer (score 0):

```
var bytes = <your_image_file_name>!.bytes;
String tempath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
File imgfile = File('$tempath/AddFile.png');
await imgfile.writeAsBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));
final InputImage inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(imageFile!);

final TextRecognizer textDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.textRecognizer();

final RecognizedText recognizedText = await textDetector.processImage(inputImage);   
final String text = recognizedText.text;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).